# Firebase The server has terminated the upload session on Mobile Network

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, 3g-network

Firebase storage(image upload) is working only with WiFi network, I can upload an image and download the same. However, the uploading is not working with mobile network(LTE/3G)

Java code:

```
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("images/"+ mImagePath);
            ref.putFile(Uri.parse("file:///"+mImagePath),metadata)
               .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
@Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
// do something

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();

                })}
```

Exception:

`The server has terminated the upload session
    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:320)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:289)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:203)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:1106)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:455)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:435)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:426)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:280)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:294)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:65)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:57)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:457)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:257)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:198)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:1106) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

Storage rules:

```
    service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  //allow read, write

}
}
}
```

Comment: any pointers, anyone face issue?

Comment: Is it a bug in Firebase?